# How can I get the return value from an `setTimeout` callback?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

consider this code

```
const obj = {
  generate(num) {
    return Math.random()*num;
  },
  add(a,b) {
    return this.generate(a) + this.generate(b)
  }
};

function delay(func, ms) {
  function wrapper() {
    setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms)  // How can I get the return value from the original function?
  }

  return wrapper;
}

// create wrappers
obj.f1000 = delay(obj.add, 1000);
obj.f1500 = delay(obj.add, 1500);

obj.f1000(1,3);
obj.f1500(2,5);
```

I made a wrapper to delay the method call for `add()`
Is there a way to retrieve the value from the callback inside setTimeout, i.e. the `this.generate(a) + this.generate(b)` from `add()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line within the wrapper:

```
setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, arguments), ms)
```

to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (ES6)

```
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(func.apply(this, arguments)), ms));
```

You can access the delayed result via `.then`.

**Update** Per OP's request, edited answer to use `async/await` insted of `then`. Since `await` needs to be called inside a function declared as `async`, we need to wrap our js code inside a new function (`main()` below):

```js
const obj = {
  generate(num) {
    return Math.random() * num;
  },
  add(a, b) {
    return this.generate(a) + this.generate(b)
  },

};

function delay(func, ms) {
  function wrapper() {
    // CHANGE THIS LINE
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(func.apply(this, arguments)), ms)); // How can I get the return value from the original function?
  }
  return wrapper;
}

//await can only work in an 'async' function
async function main() {
  obj.f1000 = delay(obj.add, 1000);
  console.time('completed');

  // add await here
  let x = await obj.f1000(1, 3); 
  console.log(x);
  console.timeEnd('completed');
}

main();
```

Comment: Could you use async/await to rewrite this example??

Comment: Yes, but to use `await` instead of `.then` you need to wrap that code inside a function which is declared as `async` first. Updated example code above.

Answer (score 0):

Since setTimeout will execute the callback asynchronously, you will need to work with Promises (ES6) or async/await (ES7).

You can [polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) it for ES5.

#### Example with promises

```js
const obj = {
  generate(num) {
    return Math.random() * num;
  },
  add(a, b) {
    return this.generate(a) + this.generate(b);
  }
};

// create promise
function timedPromise(func, args, ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // spread operator
      resolve(func.apply(null, args));
    }, ms);
  });
}

// create a function that creates a promise
function delay(func, ms) {
  function wrapper() {
    return timedPromise(func, arguments, ms);
  }

  return wrapper;
}

// obj.add uses this.generate, but 'this' was not bound to obj
obj.f1000 = delay(obj.add.bind(obj), 1000);
obj.f1500 = delay(obj.add.bind(obj), 1500);

console.info('calculating...')
const result1 = obj.f1000(1, 3);
const result2 = obj.f1500(2, 5);

result1.then(result => {
  console.info('f1000', result);
})

result2.then(result => {
  console.info('f1500', result);
})
```

In your wrapper function, you bound `this` to the callable function. But since `this` was not defined in that specific scope, you would have run into some troubles. I bound the `obj` to the `add` function while passing it to `delay()`.

Comment: Note: You can't polyfill async/await syntax. You can only transpile it (i.e. using Babel).

Comment: Could you use `async/await` to rewrite this example??